# Lein test with Selectors -- how to specify a test for multiple conditions?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have some tests which need to run using a connection to either the local MySQL database or the remote MySQL database.

I can choose which to run using something like this; the `(sql/with-conn...)` stuff sets up a dynamic binding to make the proper connection, and all subsequent calls just use the binding.

```
(sql/with-conn (sql/conn :remote)
    (test-one)  ;; will use remote db
    (test-two)) ;; will use remote db
```

Similarly,

```
(sql/with-conn (sql/conn :local)
    (test-one)  ;; will use local db
    (test-two)) ;; will use local db
```

I'd like to choose the binding from the command line by using selectors, as that appears to be the proper approach.
I tried adding metadata, so I could say `lein test :local` (after adding `:selectors {:local :local}` to my `project.clj`:

```
(deftest ^:local test-one [] ...)
(deftest ^:local test-two [] ...)
```

This works, but now I can't do `lein test :remote`.

I haven't been able to figure out how lein uses the value of the selector map, such that I can select a test with, say, `:local` or `:remote`, but not when the argument is `:cache`, which is intended to run another set of tests.

I tried adding tags to two different high level tests:

```
(deftest ^:local test-local []
    (sql/with-conn (sql/conn :local)
        (test-one)
        (test-two)))

(deftest ^:remote test-remote []
    (sql/with-conn (sql/conn :remote)
        (test-one)
        (test-two)))
```

But `lein test :local` and `lein test :remote` only calls the high level test and ignores test-one and test-two, I believe because the lower level tests in this case aren't tagged.

I tried using :only to call a high level test without metadata, and not using custom selectors, but again the lower level tests are not called.

What is odd as that when run from the Emacs Cider REPL, the high level tests do in fact run the low level tests.

So how do I run these tests from Lein, with essentially different arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last example is on the right track:

```
(deftest ^:local test-local []
    (sql/with-conn (sql/conn :local)
        (test-one)
        (test-two)))

(deftest ^:remote test-remote []
    (sql/with-conn (sql/conn :remote)
        (test-one)
        (test-two)))
```

The missing piece is that `test-one` and `test-two` need to be regular functions created with `defn`, ***not*** tests created with `deftest`.

---

**Update**

Test selectors add Clojure metadata to the test function. It is intended primarily to ***categorize*** functions as `:fast` vs `:slow`, for example. Test selectors are not intended to ***parameterize*** the test functions, however, which is what you want to do.

Your solution with profiles is more aligned with the intended usage of `lein`.  Note that profiles can be stored in more than one location (see  [the lein profile docs](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) for full information).

Profiles that are intended to stay with the project in SCM are added to `project.clj` under the `:profiles` key.  Profile info that should not be committed into SCM (such as cloud or db usernames & passwords) can be kept in `profiles.clj` that lives alongside `project.clj` but is user-specific and is NOT checked into SCM.

Comment: Yes, that worked :)  So how exactly does the selector function work?  If I wanted multiple tags to work with a given function, what do I put in the selector map?  I was also able to get this to work just now by using `with-profile` and setting up some :jvm-opts, then reading those with `(System/getProperty...)`